# Can a cable-connected computer to ADSL modem print through a WPS paired printer?

Tags: printing, wps

Well they happened to brought a printer to my office and before I go through all the trouble trying to set it up, I have a question:

I do have a computer that is cable-connected to the ADSL modem (which also provides wireless connection).

If I successfully pair the modem and the printer through the WPS button thingy, would my computer be able to print through that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes - if the printer has an wireless adapter and you use the same network it should be possible,
which printer do you got? - most network printers have an 'auto-discovery' procedure in the setup routine.
But it should be alway possible over an TCP/IP printer Port by addressing the printer directly (the setup would do the same)
btw: i would prefer to set the printers IP to an static IP address